# AngularJS Components - How do I pass in a back end variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm trying to component-ise my codebase and have come up stuck on this problem.

When using $scopes and Controllers I would pass a server token to my rest call method with ng-init. Trying to do the same with a Component is not working.

javascript

```
angular
.module('myApp', [])

.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var self = this;

  self.options = function() {
    var o = {}
    o.token = self.serverToken
    return o;
  }

  self.restData = {
    url: 'http://rest.url',
    options: self.options()
  }
})

.component('myComponent', {
  bindings: {
    restData: '<'
  },
  template: '<p>template, calls child components</p>',
  controller: function(restService) {

    this.callRestService = function() {
      restService.get(this.restData.url, this.restData.options) 
    }

    console.log(this.restData.url) // http://rest.url
    console.log(this.restData.options) // {token: undefined}
  }
})
```

html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <!-- head -->

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl as m" ng-init="m.serverToken='12345'">
    <my-component rest-data="m.restData"></my-component>
  </body>

</html>
```

How do I pass the value to the component?

Comment: You save a function as `self.optionss` with two esses, then you use `self.options()` with one ess to set an attribute `options` then you try to access an attribute `token` which you never set. Perhaps accessing `this.restData.options.token` and correcting the `ss` would help?

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out, there were a few typos. I've corrected them now, but the problem remains

Comment: Try `restData: '<'` to `restData: '@'`

Comment: you can try to use something like {{myVariable=whatever;""}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the ng-init is executed after the controller is instantiated. However you are creating your restData object during the construction of your controller at which time the serverToken is undefined.

You could build your restData object after ng-init is called with something like this:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var self = this;
  self.restData = {};

  self.init = function(token) {
    self.serverToken=token;
    self.restData = {
      url: 'http://rest.url',
      options: {token:token}
    };
  };
})
```

Your component can then do something when that restData changes. For example:

```
.component('myComponent', {
  bindings: {
    restData: '<'
  },
  template: '<p>template, calls child components</p>',
  controller: function(restService) {

    this.callRestService = function() {
       restService.get(this.restData.url, this.restData.options) 
    }

    this.$onChanges = function(changes) {

      console.log(this.restData) // http://rest.url
      console.log(this.restData.options) // {token: 12345}

      this.callRestService();
    }
  }
});
```

The HTML would change to call your init method:

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as m" ng-init="m.init(12345)">
    <my-component rest-data="m.restData"></my-component>
   </body>
```

Comment: I had tried something similar - setting the token in a function - but couldn't get it to work. Is it $onChanges that's working the magic here? This solved it for me, really nice solution.